# Object Recognition Kitchen (ORK) not installing correctly on Hydro

Tags: ros, object-recognition-kitchen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I should start by saying that I am very new to linux and ROS. I am working out of Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS hydro. I would like to use Object Recognition Kitchen (ORK) in conjunction with a Kinect for hand grasp studies. I've confirmed that ORK will work with Hydro.

I followed the install instructions for groovy given at the ORK site.

I tried straight from the ROS repositories with `ros-*-object-recognition-core` but had no luck using rosinstall.Then I tried the rosinstall file and the build kept failing.

Finally I followed the directions to download and build from source for groovy, but replaced all groovy calls with hydro. I installed all the pipelines and ROS stuff and built with catkin_make. I did not receive any errors and it looks as though it built correctly.

Just to see if everything was working I followed the quick guide for ROS packages. I set up the environment as noted, launched roscore, and launched openni successfully.

But when trying to set up the capture workspace I get this:

```
zarathustra@zarathustra-MS-7693:~$ rosrun object_recognition_capture orb_template -o my_textured_plane
[rospack] Error: stack/package object_recognition_capture not found

zarathustra@zarathustra-MS-7693:~$ rosrun object_recognition_capture orb_track --track_directory my_textured_plane
[rospack] Error: stack/package object_recognition_capture not found
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103706/object-recognition-kitchen-(ork)-not-installing-correctly-on-hydro/) by [chase](https://answers.ros.org/users/9066/chase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-11-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the problem for anyone else having similar issues: you have to make sure that ORK is installed in opt/ros/hydro/share so that it is on the correct ROS path. Otherwise you will need to source whatever path you install it under.

---

Originally posted by [chase](https://answers.ros.org/users/9066/chase/) with karma: 88 on 2013-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1